# phpseclib error bigInterger not found on line x

Tags: php, encryption, password-encryption, phpseclib

hi this my error when i want implement RSA algorithm in PHP how to fix this problem everything seems okay and i not changing anything

> Fatal error: Class 'phpseclib\Math\BigInteger' not found in
>   phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php on line 509 this is line 509 in __construct
>   method of RSA class `$this->zero = new BigInteger(0);`

how to fix this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: you're trying to use either the 2.0 version (or the master branch in github) of phpseclib and aren't using an autoloader (eg. Composer), as is required by those versions.

If you don't want to use an autoloader then you'll need to use the 1.0 branch.

Comment: is it not possible to use version 2.0 without using an autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

use below code as header

```
Phpseclib\Math\BigInteger
```

istead of

```
phpseclib\Math\BigInteger
```

name start with Capital later in update versions. It resolved my issue